# What is the difference between LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage()) and LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage(), exception)

Tags: java, spring, log4j2, apache-commons, java.util.logging

[Like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0lhq.jpg)

I know that both of them works fine but I just wanted to know how are they different from each other? PS: I am a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`LogEvent`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent.html) can contain both a message and an exception. If you use the first form:

```java
LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage());
```

only the error message will be recorded and you'll have a similar output in your logs (depends upon the layout):

```
[ERROR] - Exception message.
```

If you use the second form:

```java
LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
```

you'll have **both** a message and an exception. This typically outputs the stack trace in the logs:

```
[ERROR] - Exception message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception message.
    at pl.copernik.log4j.Log4j2Test.run(Log4j2Test.java:19) [classes/:?]
    at pl.copernik.log4j.Log4j2Test.main(Log4j2Test.java:15) [classes/:?]
```

Since you can always configure Log4j 2.x to suppress stack traces from the output (see `alwaysWriteExceptions` in the [`PatternLayout` documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout)), the second form is always better, as it provides more information.

**Remark:** Since the stack trace always prints the error's message, I'd suggest a third form:

```
LOGGER.error("An unexpected condition occurred while performing foo: {}",
    exception.getMessage(), exception);
```

This way you can explain the context, when the exception occurred:

```
[ERROR] - An unexpected condition occurred while performing foo: Exception message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception message.
    at pl.copernik.log4j.Log4j2Test.run(Log4j2Test.java:19) [classes/:?]
    at pl.copernik.log4j.Log4j2Test.main(Log4j2Test.java:15) [classes/:?]
```